# Attempt to read property "id" on int? i can`t find solution

Tags: laravel

i am trying to make @admin @endadmin in view to control some access in my project

```
@admin

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="sidebar-link {{ Str::startsWith($route,'role.index') ? 'actived' : '' }} " href="{{ route('role.index') }}">
        <span class="icon-holder">
            <i class="c-brown-500 ti-user"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="title">roles</span>
    </a>
</li>

@endadmin
```

and in app service provider in boot function

```
Blade::if('admin',function(){

    return auth()->check() && auth()->user()->isposs();
});
```

and in user model:

```
 public function isposs(){
     return $this->role->id==10:
 }
```

i need to make simple cms

Comment: Is `$this->role` is a foreign key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `$this->role` is an int value. So first check that with `dd($this->role)` to see the real value.

The error message says that it cannot access `id` prop on an int value like i.e.: 9, you cannot do `$this->9->id`.

`$this->role` must return a relationship or something, more like a class, instead of an int.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scope inside of your `User` model

```
public function scopeIsPoss(Builder $query){
    return $query->role->id == 10;
}
```

then you can call

```
auth()->user()->isPoss();
```